# Angular - how do I use $resource

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I have this controller that is working correctly for an Angular UI typeahead. How would I add the server call as a resource?

```
var receivableApp = angular.module('receivableApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource'])
.controller('ReceivableController', function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.Debtors = function (term) {        
        return $http.get('/Receivable/GetDebtors/?term=' + term).then(function (response) {                
            return response.data;
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
receivableApp.factory('GetDebtors', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
        return $resource('/Receivable/GetDebtors/');
    }]);
```

This will add a service `GetDebtors` with a default `GET`, and other REST handlers.

Now, to make a call inside your controller, you can do:

```
debtControllers.controller('DebtCtrl', ['$scope', 'GetDebtors',
    $scope.debts = GetDebtors.get({term: 'foo'});
]);
```

This is equivalent to making a call to `/Receivable/GetDebtors/?term=foo`.

If you want to change the behavior, you can override the default methods available on `$resource`. More details can be found [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource).

Answer (score 0):

$resource was meant to retrieve data from an endpoint, manipulate it and send it back.

It's fine to have custom methods on your resource, but you don't want to miss out on the cool features it comes with OOTB.var Todo = $resource('/api/1/todo/:id');

//create a todo var todo1 = new Todo(); 
todo1.foo = 'bar';
 todo1.something = 123;
 todo1.$save();

Comment: Thanks Paul. I really wanted an example based on my code above. I have seen all the Todo examples but I need to know how to pass the parameter etc. That's why I marked up the answer above.

Comment: The action methods on the class object or instance object can be invoked with the following parameters: HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error]) non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error]) non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])

Comment: Syntax of making call based on parameters